# this keyword with select box onchange attribute in Safaari vs. Chrome, Firefox, IE

Tags: javascript, safari, this, drop-down-menu, selectedindex

Tested in Chrome 20, FF 13, IE 9, Safari 5.1.7.

Can anyone tell me why the following code works in Chrome, Firefox and IE, but not in Safari?

```
<select id="mySelectBox" onChange="window.open(options[selectedIndex].value);">
<option value="" selected="selected" >Choose a search engine.</option>
<option value="http://www.google.com" >Google</option>
<option value="http://www.bing.com" >Bing</option>
<option value="http://www.yahoo.com" >Yahoo</option>
</select>
```

My feeling is that Safari is doing the right thing.  I shouldn't be able to reference the options property and selectedIndex property without using the this keyword or the more verbose document.getElementById('mySelectBox').

What's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the "Block Pop-up Windows" setting checked? If so, that's what's stopping it.

Comment: @j08691, you are a smart man.  I am a silly man.  Thanks!

Comment: I'll post that as an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Safari's "Block Pop-up Windows" setting checked that will stop this from working.

Comment: This is also blocked in Chrome now as well.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466129/window-open-blocked-by-chrome-with-change-event