# 'window.open' blocked by Chrome with change event

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, onchange

I am trying to open a window based on an onChange event on a select element without getting blocked by Chrome's popup blocker.

The problem is demonstrated here.

https://jsfiddle.net/yyfe0824/1/

```
<select class="dropdown-select" onChange="window.open('https://www.google.com');">
    <option value="uno">Uno</option>
    <option value="dos">Dos</option>
    <option value="tres">Tres</option>
</select>

<input type="button" onClick="window.open('https://www.google.com');" value="click me">
```

There is no problem with a window.open call on the 'click me' button, but if you try to change the select dropdown, chrome will block the popup.

So far, answers to this problem have been specific to the onClick event. Doing research reveals that Chrome will block popups if it detects that it is not user triggered via some sort of handler, so I'm specifically trying to call the function inline, rather than using another named function.

Is this the intended behavior of window.open, specifically for onChange and if so, is there any particular workaround? (Aside from changing the structure to be a click event in the first place.)

Comment: It does not matter if you use `window.open` inline or in a named function. The browser will check if the call stack has its origin in an user interaction and if it is an interaction that allows to open a popup the `window.open` would not be blocked.

Comment: @JuanMendes I know that it is an user interaction. I just wanted to say that it does not matter where `open` is called (inline vs in some function), but that the origin/root for the call-stack needs to be an user-interaction that allows `window.open`

Comment: @CliffBurton if your solutions works but not the one with `onchange` then you should considere it as browser bug and not as a reliable solution.

Comment: @JuanMendes `onchange="$('#buttonID').click();"`  either does not create a real event at all because jquery has its own internal event handling  or it creates a user initiated event, as of that a click event created that way should not allow `window.open` to work, otherwise you could open as many windows as you would like to. So if `onchange="$('#buttonID').click();"`   would allow to call a `window.open` but not a direct `onchange="window.open(...)"` then it is more a browser bug then a solution.

Comment: @JuanMendes and how does your statement differ to what I have said. CliffBurton claimed that  `onchange="$('#buttonID').click();"` works for him. But if `onchange="$('#buttonID').click();"` somehow calls the `onClick="window.open('https://www.google.com');"` of the `button` and this really opens a window but `onChange="window.open('https://www.google.com');"`  does not, it is a bug that the `window.open` opens a window in that case

Comment: @JuanMendes I don't want to say that opening a window in `onchange` is a bug (for me `window.open` even works in `onchange` in chrome). But if the browser decides blocks `window.open` for `onchange`, then  I should also block the `window.open` for every code that was called cause of an action that was done in `onchange`, so if the `onClick="window.open('https://www.google.com');"` is called programmatically by the  `onChange="$('input').click()"` then the `window.open` should be block for this particular case, otherwise it is a bug.

Comment: @t.niese I agree, but I personally think the browser should block everything except clicks on links, maybe buttons would be OK also. I, like most web surfers, hate popups.

Comment: Works for me, cannot reproduce

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is by design, the only time browsers don't block `window.open` is when you are handling a `click` event.

My suggestion is to provide a link that changes when users select from the dropdown.

I advise against opening a popup because users don't expect a popup when you select from a drop down, that is why popup blockers don't typically allow this. Even if you find something that works in a browser (https://jsfiddle.net/yyfe0824/5/ in Firefox), it could break in the future.

Comment: This is very subjective, for example i'd like to open a pdf in new window, when user selects from select dropbox "view pdf" among other options...

Comment: @Miguel The subjectivity isn't relevant. This is just how browsers work. Just use a custom menu with an `<a>` instead of a `<select>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to work around this by having click wired up and simply determine if the new selected item matches the previous selected item.

I've edited the previous [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/38b3uts3/6/) to make it work.

```
dropdown.addEventListener('click', Foo);    
function Foo(e)
{
    var selectedIndex = dropdown.selectedIndex;
    if(selectedIndex !== oldSelectedIndex)
    {
        var val = dropdown.options[selectedIndex].value;
        var opened = window.open(val);
        oldSelectedIndex = selectedIndex;
    }
}
```